Deciding between firebases onSnapshot and Cloud Functions?
useEffect(()=>{
    if(!user){
      return;
    }
    const creationTime = user.metadata?.creationTime;

    if (!creationTime) {
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    const userCreationDate = new Date(creationTime);
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const diffTime = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - userCreationDate.getTime());
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    const db = getFirestore(app);
    const userRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);

    if (diffDays < 7) {
      setIsSubscribed(true);
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    const unsubscribeSnapshot = onSnapshot(userRef, (userDoc) => {
      console.log('In unsubscribeSnapshot');
      if (userDoc.exists()) {
        const userData = userDoc.data();
        const subscribed = userData.isSubscribed;

        if (!subscribed) {
          router.push('/signUp');
          setLoading(false);
          return;
        }
        setIsSubscribed(subscribed);
      } else {
        setIsSubscribed(false);
        router.push('/signUp');
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    setUnsubscribeSnapshot(() => unsubscribeSnapshot);

    return () => {
      if (unsubscribeSnapshot) {
        unsubscribeSnapshot();
      }
    };
  },[router, user]);


import { FirebaseApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const updateSubscriptionStatus = async (
  app: FirebaseApp,
  isSubscribed: boolean,
  customerId: string,
) => {
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const userId = auth.currentUser?.uid;
  if (!userId) {
    console.error('User is not authenticated');
    throw new Error('User is not authenticated');
  }

  const db = getFirestore(app);
  const userRef = doc(db, 'users', userId);
  await setDoc(userRef, { isSubscribed, stripeCustomerId: customerId }, { merge: true });
};

export default updateSubscriptionStatus;


  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);

    const result = (await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      redirect: 'if_required',
    })) as PaymentIntentResult;

    if (result.error) {
      setMessage(result.error.message || 'An unexpected error occurred.');
    } else if (result.paymentIntent && result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
      try {
        await updateSubscriptionStatus(app, true, customerId);
        setMessage('Payment successful!');
        router.push('/thanks');
      } catch (error) {
        setMessage('Failed to update subscription status.');
        console.error(error);
      }
    } else {
      setMessage('Payment processing.');
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };


I'm currently managing a subscription system where each user receives a seven-day free trial. During this trial, the local isSubscribed variable is set to true, allowing the user to access all pages. After the trial period ends, isSubscribed is set to false, and a corresponding variable in Firestore is created and updated to false. This restricts access to all pages, and the user is redirected to the sign-up page.
Once the user completes the sign-up process and sets up their monthly subscription, both the Firestore isSubscribed variable and the local isSubscribed variable are updated to true, restoring access to the pages.
I've also set up a Stripe API webhook to automatically update the Firestore isSubscribed status based on the success or failure of monthly payments, which in turn updates the local isSubscribed variable.
My question is whether I should use Cloud Functions instead of onSnapshot, considering that I will have approximately 1,000 users, each undergoing a seven-day free trial, and that their isSubscribed status will be determined by their monthly payments.
I’m currently using onSnapshot, and it's functioning well, but I'm concerned about its performance and cost implications.

To understand better, are you looking for an answer that indicates which solution is better for updating a Firestore document through the client or Cloud Functions?

yes im trying to decide what option is more suitable taking into account performance and cost


My question is whether I should use Cloud Functions instead of onSnapshot, considering that I will have approximately 1,000 users, each undergoing a seven-day free trial, and that their isSubscribed status will be determined by their monthly payments.


I’m currently using onSnapshot, and it's functioning well, but I'm concerned about its performance and cost implications.

Before taking care of performance and cost implications, you should understand the difference between these two approaches. First of all, you should know that the way onSnapshot (real-time listeners) work is not compatible with the way Cloud Functions works. Cloud Functions for Firebase can only run for a limited period of time, which is a maximum of 9 minutes, as far as I know, and right after that it will be shut down. So you cannot use them instead of listeners. So Cloud Functions are definitely not well suited for situations where you need to listen for real-time updates for longer periods of time. On the other hand, real-time listeners will continue to listen until they are explicitly removed. So if you try to attach a listener inside a Cloud Function, the Firebase servers will still shut it down after 9 minutes.
So I recommend you attach a real-time listener on the client so you can always get real-time updates from the Firebase servers and use Cloud Function only to respond to events that take place inside documents in Firestore.

Ah, I see! The documentation was a bit hard to follow. My main concern with using onSnapshot is whether it could cause performance issues or increase costs. I had originally set up snapshots for managing the isSubscribed status and sessions, but I’m worried that having something running constantly in the background might be inefficient. Are these concerns valid? If so, what alternative would you recommend?

I don't see any performance issues when using a real-time listener. When it comes to costs, try always to remove the lister when it is not needed anymore.

I apologize for the delay—I was out of town. Regarding the cost, I assumed it would be expensive and potentially overload the server since it needs to run continuously for up to 2,000 users. The goal of this code is to offer users a seven-day free trial. After the trial, they must subscribe via Stripe, which will update the isSubscribed value in Firestore. This value controls access to certain pages in the software. I need the system to listen in real-time so that changes, like payment failures, immediately update the user's subscription status.

In such a case, you should use a real-time listener on the client and use Cloud Functions to take action when something changes in Firestore. When it comes to costs, you should do some math to see the real impact on your budget. But I think that 2k users is a reasonable number of users.

Thanks for your answer! Just to clarify—you're saying that having an open listener for each user (so around 2,000 open listeners) wouldn’t really impact performance? I’m still new to all this, so the idea of having that many listeners running at once seems like it could cause a bottleneck. Also, would you recommend updating the Firestore isSubscribed value server-side? I’m currently handling it client-side using setDoc. Sorry for all the questions!

If all your users are around 2k, it is quite unlikely that all users will be online and have active listers simultaneously. Even if so, 2k is not such a big number. In my opinion, all operations that can take place on the server must be handled by the backend rather than by the client.  Why? That's because a backend server can be considered a trusted environment, while the code that runs on the client cannot.

Awesome, thank you so much for the help.

Good to hear that. So can I help you with other information?
